# How do I output a proper resolution/frequency in text mode?

Tags: linux, display, arch-linux

[ Full disclosure: [I asked this question first](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172052) on the Arch Linux forums, and got no answer ]

I have a server which generally runs headless. It doesn't run X at all -- just the CLI.

This server used to have a big clunky CRT that I would plug in whenever I needed to troubleshoot something. This worked fine, but the CRT (though small) weighs as much as a midsize sedan. Recently I got a small secondhand LCD panel to replace it with.

The problem is, when I plug in the LCD and turn it on, it says "The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change your input timing to 1280x1024 @ 60Hz".

If I reboot the server (which I normally do about once a year, so it's not an optimal solution), the monitor works...until I unplug it. Then when I plug it back in and turn it on, I get the same message again until I reboot.

(Using DVI would probably solve this problem, but the server does not have a DVI port)

How do I make the server output 60Hz video in such a way that it keeps working across unplug/plug cycles? Bonus points will be awarded for answers which don't require a reboot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a startling display of competence, I fixed this myself!

I did this:

- In /etc/default/grub

  - Set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
  - Add the line GRUB_TERMINAL=console
  - Add the line GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
  - Remove the GRUB_GFXMODE line
- Rerun grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

The downside is I get big chunky text at not-great resolution instead of nice framebuffered text at a reasonable resolution. The upside is that it works, unlike any of the above.

Comment: +1 great solution, now I can see what my server is doing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the framebuffer.
Just edit `/etc/grub.conf` and add `vga=794` to the end of the lines that begin with kernel.

`vga=793` 15-bit 1280x1024@60
`vga=794` 16-bit 1280x1024@60
`vga=795` 24-bit 1280x1024@60

Depending on the age of the monitor, you may need to try one of the other codes.
Sorry, you will have to reboot until you get it working, then it will be fine.

Comment: Does this really change the frequency?  I have an old ATI video chip (product: Rage XL PCI
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
) and I think it's sending at 48Hz.

Comment: It's only been 4 years since I posted this?  Looking back, I don't think this defines the frequency at all.  

In my experience, newer monitors will take whatever refresh rate is under the maximum for the display.  There is some good documentation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions

Comment: Bet you never thought you'd see this post again.  It worked, though!  I put vga=791 on the grub command line and at least I got *something* to work until I can figure out the correct combination for this card/monitor (Samsumg P2370HD).  Thanks, again!

Comment: Sweet!  I don't think you can really break anything with this, and if you DO pick the wrong resolution you can always break into the grub menu on boot, edit the line that has the vga settings and try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`fbset`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_fbset.htm)? Using this to set the correct framebuffer mode should work.

I haven't used Arch much since they switched to systemd, but this has worked well in the past.

Comment: I am having difficulty trying this...I type 'fbset "1280x1024-60"', but that does not appear to actually change anything, and it doesn't make the monitor work (I'm typing this into an ssh terminal, if that matters).

Comment: Try `fbset -xres 1280 -yres 1024`. I haven't ever had to change the timings, but `man fbset` will tell you the syntax for doing that.

Comment: The man page is remarkably unhelpful...I see a section on timings, but I suspect I need to have a degree in electrical engineering just to understand that section...

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
 sudo udevadm trigger
```

From the Arch udevadm manual page:

> **udevadm trigger [options]**
>
> Request device events from the kernel. Primarily used to replay events at system coldplug time.

Comment: This does not appear to solve the problem